# Nuget doesn't recognize installed packages after upgrade to NuGet 2.7

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I just upgraded to NuGet 2.7 and followed the [Migrate to automatic package restore walkthrough](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore). After that, I noticed that NuGet didn't recognize the installed packages properly:

- A build didn't download the packages and consequently the build failed.
- The package was not listed under "installed" when selecting "Manage NuGet Packages" on the project.
- When browsing for online packages, there was however a green tick on installed packages, so I could not install them, even though the "installed" tab did not list them.

I concluded that the packages were only half recognized as installed by NuGet 2.7, so I manually removed one line from the packages.config and then reinstalled that package. This shows an interesting change in the csproj file (diff view):

```
  -  <Reference Include="xunit, Version=1.9.2.1705, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8d05b1bb7a6fdb6c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  -    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  +  <Reference Include="xunit">
       <HintPath>..\packages\xunit.1.9.2\lib\net20\xunit.dll</HintPath>
     </Reference>
```

The first two lines were replaced by the third. After that, the package was properly installed again.

So how can I get my packages properly installed again, without performing the above procedure for each package on each project?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to restore proper behavior for all packages at once. But a single package can be reinstalled for all projects using the command line:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall <package-name>
```

After that, the package is correctly recognized as installed and will be restored properly. However, this approach is still cumbersome, so if someone has a better approach, that would be nice!